# UDPClient.Send to a specific IP/Port is not sending, nor is it throwing an exception

Tags: python, .net, vb.net, udpclient

I'm trying to pull a small python script's functionality into a VB Application. The App is testing the UDP communication with a custom PCBA. The PCBA will send a specific message to the App, which should receive the message and echo it back, thus completing the test. I'd like to migrate this functionality into the VB so I don't have the shell the python script out, which works, but is not as easy to distribute.

The problem is that while the python code works as expected, the VB code isn't echoing back. It doesn't throw exceptions, it does receive the initial message, checks the message for the word "Loopback" and attempts to respond by sending the received bytes back. However, the bytes are not being sent. Why?

The python script that works is:

```
import socket
import sys
import string

lb = "Loopback"
# Create a UDP socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
# Bind the socket to the port
server_address = ('192.168.1.99', 10000)
sock.bind(server_address)
while True:
    print('\nWaiting to receive message')
    data, address = sock.recvfrom(512)
    print('>>> %s' % data)
    if lb in data.decode():
        #if lb in data:
        sock.sendto(data, address)
        print('Sent %d bytes back to %s' % (len(data), address))
```

Attempting to achieve the same functionality in Visual Basic (that isn't working) is:

```
Dim udpClient As New UdpClient(10000)
        Dim RemoteIpEndPoint As New IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.99"), 10000)
        Dim receiveBytes As Byte()
        Dim returnData As String

        While True
            receiveBytes = udpClient.Receive(RemoteIpEndPoint)
            returnData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receiveBytes)

            Console.WriteLine(RemoteIpEndPoint.Address.ToString() + ":" + returnData.ToString())
            Try
                If returnData.ToString().Contains("Loopback") Then
                    udpClient.Connect(RemoteIpEndPoint)
                    Dim reply As Integer = udpClient.Send(receiveBytes, receiveBytes.Length, RemoteIpEndPoint)
                    Console.WriteLine("Replied:" + reply.ToString() + " to : " + RemoteIpEndPoint.Address.ToString() + ", Port: " + RemoteIpEndPoint.Port.ToString())
                End If
            Catch ex As SocketException
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ErrorCode.ToString())
            End Try
        End While
```

When I monitor the communication via WireShark while running the VB Echo code, I can see the received packets, but there are none echoed back as with the Python Echo code.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the Send part, so I don't know if this is the correct answer.

1. Check your firewall
2. Remove the udpClient.Connect(RemoteIpEndPoint) source part

```
Dim udpClient As New UdpClient(10000)
Dim RemoteIpEndPoint As New IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.99"), 10000)
Dim receiveBytes As Byte()
Dim returnData As String

receiveBytes = udpClient.Receive(RemoteIpEndPoint)
returnData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receiveBytes)

      While True
            receiveBytes = udpClient.Receive(RemoteIpEndPoint)
            returnData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receiveBytes)

            Console.WriteLine(RemoteIpEndPoint.Address.ToString() + ":" + returnData.ToString())
            Try
               If returnData.ToString().Contains("Loopback") Then
                  ' udpClient.Connect(RemoteIpEndPoint)
                  Dim reply As Integer = udpClient.Send(receiveBytes, receiveBytes.Length, RemoteIpEndPoint)
                  Console.WriteLine("Replied:" + reply.ToString() + " to : " + RemoteIpEndPoint.Address.ToString() + ", Port: " + RemoteIpEndPoint.Port.ToString())
               End If
            Catch ex As SocketException
               Console.WriteLine(ex.ErrorCode.ToString())
            End Try
         End While
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, there is no Firewall and, it still doesn't throw an Exception without the udpClient.Connect, but also does not send. Thank you though, Think2826